# How to understand the structure 'of ..., is...'

Tags: grammar

The flowing sentence is picked from ***The Critique of Pure Reason***
But how to understand the structure 'of ..., is...'

> Of far more importance than all that has been above said, is the
>   consideration that certain of our cognitions rise completely above the
>   sphere of all possible experience

Comment: The base structure is just the normal "X is of Y". *The consideration is of importance.* The author then simply switches around the two parts to put emphasis on the Y. "Of importance is the consideration". It's still saying the exact same thing as before, but now the word *importance* is even more prominent. So the reader understands it must be a really really important consideration.

Comment: It is clear now, thank you for your concise answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use of *of* is explained in *Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p465):

> You can sometimes use **of** and a noun group to describe something,
>   instead of using an adjective and a submodifier. For example, instead
>   of saying that something is 'very interesting', you can say that it is
>   **of great interest**. This is a rather formal use.
>
> - It will be *of great interest* to you.
> - The result is *of little importance*.
> - ...a film *of considerable character and intelligence*.

You could restate Kant's sentence as:

> Far more important than all that has been above said is the
>   consideration that certain of our cognitions rise completely above the
>   sphere of all possible experience.

But as the usage guide states, the noun phrase is a little more formal and thus better suited to such a philosophical text.

Comment: It may be more appropriate to restate as below. Switching around subject and predicate just for emphasizing.


`The consideration that certain of our cognitions rise completely above the sphere of all possible experience, is far more important than all that has been above said.`

Comment: Yes, you could restate the sentence in the way you suggest. But then you change the theme or topic of the sentence. See @RegDwigнt's comment. Here's more about theme/topic from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment